# Calling a new instance to DB asp.net MVC web api

Tags: asp.net, database

I'm a bit new to this but it seems to be that when I lodge a JSON get request to my web api developed in ASP.NET MVC my controller goes along, opens a new instance to the db and then grabs my data
for example\

```
        public Array getalldata()
    {
        return myData.AllVal();
    }
```

i feel like this is kind of redundant, can we not just keep a reference open?

Thanks for the help!

Adam

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol by design. This means that each request gets a corresponding response without knowing anything about prior requests. And ASP.NET MVC and Web API follow those good practices.

So if you want to avoid hitting your database on each request you might consider caching the results in memory or on the client. Obviously this comes with its problems because if the data in your database is updated you will need to invalidate this cache or clients might get stale data. So for rarely changing data, caching might optimize the performance but bear in mind that this get quickly turn into a nightmare if you have frequent updates.